# Approach to Finding a Basis and Proving/Showing a Basis of a set.

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok, so I just want to clear up this confusion in my head.

If I have a subset S and I have to find a basis, I would put the vectors equal to zero, row-reduce it and then pick the pivots to get my basis.

But if I have a set S and I need to show that it's a basis of a larger set, there are conflicting answers in my notes and online. One side says to check for linear independence of the coefficients only. If they only have a trivial solution. You then move onto seeing if the dimension of the given set is equal or less than the the dimension of the given set to check if it is spanning it or not.

But then there are solutions where first we check if it spans first or not by putting in general elements, seeing if they span and then just equate the final equations to 0 for LI.
My question is if the first approach is right, then why do a lot of the solutions check if the set spans first or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a basis for an $n$ dimensional space (for example, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is 2-dimensional), then you need $n$ linearly independent vectors.

In particular, if you have a set of $k$ linearly independent vectors, then these form a basis for a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but don't form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself. If you want to extend these $k$ linearly independent vectors to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, you need to add $n-k$ more linearly independent vectors.

So in other words, you need to check two things: (1) that your set of vectors is linearly independent and (2) you have enough vectors for it to span the whole space. If I understand correctly, those two methods above are exactly the same, but they are just checking these two conditions in a different order. To put it in a different way, the thing you said about "equating the equation to 0," I think, is to check that the vectors are linearly independent, which is condition (1). Then, to check the span, you are checking condition (2). Checking these conditions are two separate processes and both need to be checked, but it doesn't really matter the order in which you check them. Hope this helps!